# Python: What does *= mean?

Tags: python

In Python, what does it mean when `*=` is used.  For example:

```
for i in xrange(len(files)):
    itimes[i,:,:] *= thishdr["truitime"]
```

Comment: @Luke Singham I approved your edit. When editing, please also [remove things like "thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333).

Answer (score 15):

As others have explained, this is roughly an equivalent to:

```
[object] = [object] * [another_object]
```

However, it's not exactly the same. Technically, the above calls the `__mul__` function, which returns a value, and reassign it back to the name.

For example, we have an object `A` and multiplying it with `B`. The process is something like this:

```
> Call the __mul__ function of object A, 
> Retrieve the new object returned.
> Reassign it to the name A.
```

Looks simple. Now, by doing `*=` we're not invoking the method `__mul__`, but instead `__imul__`, which will attempt to modify itself. The process is something like this:

```
> Call the __imul__ function of object A,
> __imul__ will change the value of the object, it returns the modified object itself
> The value is reassigned back to the name A, but still points to the same place in memory.
```

With this, you're modifying it in-place, not creating a new object.

*So what? It looks the same..*

Not exactly. If you replaces an object, you created a new place for it in memory. If you modify it in-place, the object location in the memory will always be the same.

Take a look at this console session:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> c = 10
>>> a = a * c
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

If we check the memory address:

```
>>> id(a) == id(b)
```

False

Using this, the value of `b` is unchanged, since `a` is now just pointing to a different place. But using `*=`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> c = 10
>>> a *= c
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

And if we check the memory address:

```
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
```

The operation affects `b` as well. This can be tricky and leading to confusing behaviours, sometimes. But once you understand it, it would be easy to handle.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `__imul__` *does* return its result (which is usually `self`), and that result *is* assigned back to the variable.

Comment: Now, i'm the one confused. Turns out i know less than i thought. @lvc Can you please help me understand it? What's the actual difference? Meanwhile, i'll delete my answer. Can you come to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)?

Comment: Ah wait, i think i understand.

Answer (score 9):

It just means "[expression on the left] = [itself] * [expression on the right]":

`itimes[i,:,:] *= thishdr["truitime"]`

is equivalent to

`itimes[i,:,:] = itimes[i,:,:] * thishdr["truitime"]`

Comment: Well, technically it invokes the `__imul__` method of the left hand side, which could do anything.

Comment: It attempts to perform the multiplication in-place, if the left-hand side implements an in-place version.

Comment: In a similar vein, `+=`, `-=`, `/=`, `//=` `&=`, `|=`, `<<=`, `**=`, `>>=`, and `^=` should all do what you expect them to, assuming you have reasonable definitions of `__imul__`, `__iadd__`, etc.

Comment: @Marcin good point, but operator overloading (that doesn't conform to what one would expect from *) is really really really bad practice.  It breaks the elegance of the language.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon So...I shouldn't bother telling people about it? What's your point here?

Comment: @Marcin I was not implying that at all, I was implying that one should expect the `*` operator to behave as such as not as `could do anything` that's the kind of overloading that makes C++ so terrible.

Comment: behave as such; not as `could do anything`

Comment: @MikeMcMahon There's no reason why `__imul__` can't do anything. Python is no different from C++ in that respect.

Comment: @Marcin Right, but you've broken your contract with the mind and language elegance when suddenly `YourClass *= 5` changes traditional Chinese to Standard Chinese.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html.  Can you do anything, of course, but should one, absolutely not.  There are other ways and overloading an operator to work outside the bounds of what is expected is just bad bad code smell

Comment: @MikeMcMahon Unless there's a secret police that stops such code going into production, I don't see the value of that observation in this context. Users of Python need to be aware of operator overloading.

Comment: @Marcin now you're just being patronizing.  I never said we should preclude python programmers from knowing about it.  Of course your code *can* do anything, but by all means it should not when dealing with operator overloading.  Easily one of the areas of development that can introduce big headaches.

Answer (score 1):

It means "set this variable to itself times "

```
>>> fred = 10
>>> fred *= 10                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> fred                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> barney = ["a"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
>>> barney *= 10                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> barney 
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```